# If an app has the permission "Draw over other apps", can the app see the content present on my screen?

Tags: security, permissions, password

So I recently installed an app called XSCamera which can basically record with the phone camera in the background. It requires the "Draw over other apps" permission to display a mini-preview of the viewfinder at the bottom of the screen. But can the app also see the content which is present on my screen with this permission? I have documents in my phone which have my passwords and other personal information. If I use this app and then open those documents, can the app see my passwords?